# Distribution of sum of binomial outcomes with logit-normally distributed probabilities (something like a poisson binomial?)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I've got a series of probabilities estimated as the fitted values of a logistic regression.  Call them $\hat y_i$.  I've got them on the logit scale, so one can get the estimated probability as $(1+e^{-\hat y_i})^{-1}$.  The logit model is somewhat uncertain; I've also got standard errors of $\hat y_i$, call them $se(\hat y_i)$.

Given **both** uncertainty in the outcome of the Bernouli trials, **and** uncertainty in **each** Bernouli trial's probability, what is the probability mass function for the sum of the many Bernouli trials?  Is this possible to get it analytically?

To clarify:
I start with a logistic regression model 
$$
pr(y = 1) = logit(\mathbf{X'\beta}+\epsilon)
$$
which gets me $\mathbf{X'\hat\beta} = \hat y$ on the logit scale.  Each $\hat y_i$ is associated with different $\mathbf{X}_i$, so will yield a different estimated probability $\widehat{pr}_i = (1+e^{-\hat y_i})^{-1}$.  In addition, each $\hat y$ is associated with a standard error, so that each $\hat y_i$ is (asymptoticaly) $\mathcal{N}(\hat y, se(\hat y))$ on the logit scale.  So the confidence intervals on the probabilities aren't symmetrical unless $\hat y = 0$.

OK.  So you see that there is uncertainty about whether $pr_i$ will manifest as a one or a zero.  You also see that there is uncertainty about the $pr_i$ itself.  Now, say I have $i = 1,2,...,n$.  What is the distribution of 
$$
\displaystyle\sum_n y_i
$$
which is an integer between zero and $n$?  It will be the sum of many bernouli trials, each of which has a different probability, of which each has a different distribution.

Edit:  Sorry for any confusion re: the writing of $\hat y$ as being on the logit scale and $y$ as being the $0/1$ outcome.

Comment: Getting it analytically would save me a TON of processor time...

Comment: Sum of what "many Bernoulli trials"?  N future trials each assumed to have the same, but unknown, probability?  Or are you talking about summing Bernoulli trials each of which has a different probability?

Comment: Edited question.  That clarify?